# Getting the Average of multiple rows in ms access 2010 using c#

Tags: c#, ms-access

Hi i am making a Employee evaluation program and i need to get the average of each employee per field in order to accomplish this the employee is being insterted into a new row everytime he/she is being evaluate so as not to overwrite the previous person's evaluation of that employee i have my code and is not throwing errors but is not writing the average to the database

```
public void AvOut()
{
    try
    {
        string request = tbEmployee.Text;
        //Opens a connection to the database
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString);
        conn.Open();

        OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [Admin].[OutPuts] FROM [Admin] WHERE EmployeeName ='" + request + "';";
        OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        int total = 0;
        int count = 0;

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            total += (int)reader["OutPuts"];
            count++;
        }

        int avg = total / count;

        OleDbCommand cmds = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmds.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(EmployeeID) AS [id_no] FROM [Admin];";
        OleDbDataReader dbReader = cmds.ExecuteReader();
        dbReader.Read();
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(dbReader["id_no"]);

        OleDbCommand tot = conn.CreateCommand();
        tot.CommandText = (@"UPDATE [Admin] SET AVGOutput ='" + avg + "' WHERE EmployeeID = " + id);
        int affected = tot.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The exception is " + e.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not seem to have a good database design. It would be a good idea to correct this before going any further. For example, you should have at least two and possibly three tables: `Employee`, `Outputs` and possibly`Performance`. The Employee table should contain the EmployeeID and an employee name in two or more parts (family name, given name, etc). The Outputs table should contain only the EmployeeID, not the name. It should not contain the averages, because it will have more than one line for each employee. CONT ...

Comment: .. CONT Averages should go in the performance table, so you can have averages for particular dates. However, you may not need this table at all, because you should be able to get all the information you need from queries. I suggest you read up on SQL and queries before doing any more work. [`Fundamental MS Jet SQL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140011%28office.10%29.aspx) --
[`Intermediate MS Jet SQL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140015%28office.10%29.aspx) --
[`Advanced MS Jet SQL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa139977%28office.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You may try removing the single quotes around avg. So your query should be :

```
tot.CommandText = (@"UPDATE [Admin] SET AVGOutput =" + avg + " WHERE EmployeeID = " + id);
```

Also put a break point and see if you are getting anything in avg and also check id